# Neo4j get add query for returned nodes

Tags: neo4j

I execute query

```
MATCH (translation:TlTranslation) 
WITH translation 
MATCH (lang:TlLanguage)-[lt_r:LANGUAGE_TRANSLATION_REL]->(translation),
(translation)-[tf_r:TRANSLATION_FRAGMENT_REL]->(fragment:TlFragment),
(fragment)<-[bf_r:BLOCK_FRAGMENT_REL]-(block:TlBlock),
(block)<-[db_r:DOMAIN_BLOCK_REL]-(domain:TlDomain)
RETURN {kind: 'node', labels: labels(translation), 
id: id(translation), column: "translation"} AS __meta_translation,
translation, 
{kind: 'node', labels: labels(lang), id: id(lang), column: "lang"} AS __meta_lang, 
lang, 
{kind: 'node', labels: labels(fragment), id: id(fragment), column: "fragment"} AS __meta_fragment, 
fragment, 
{kind: 'node', labels: labels(block), id: id(block), column: "block"} AS __meta_block, 
block, 
{kind: 'node', labels: labels(domain), id: id(domain), column: "domain"} AS __meta_domain, 
domain, 
{kind: 'relationship', type: type(lt_r), startId: id(startNode(lt_r)),
endId: id(endNode(lt_r)), id: id(lt_r), column: "lt_r"} AS __meta_lt_r,
lt_r, 
{kind: 'relationship', type: type(tf_r), startId: id(startNode(tf_r)),
endId: id(endNode(tf_r)), id: id(tf_r), column: "tf_r"} AS __meta_tf_r,
tf_r, 
{kind: 'relationship', type: type(bf_r), startId: id(startNode(bf_r)),
endId: id(endNode(bf_r)), id: id(bf_r), column: "bf_r"} AS __meta_bf_r,
bf_r, 
{kind: 'relationship', type: type(db_r), startId: id(startNode(db_r)),
endId: id(endNode(db_r)), id: id(db_r), column: "db_r"} AS __meta_db_r,
db_r
```

and I get some nodes and relation.
How can i get an add-query for this nodes ( which was returned)?
I can't find right answer.
Please help!

Comment: Hi, are you using the .NET client for this - if so what code are you using to call it? Also - when you say an 'Add-query' for the nodes - do you mean you want to store these back into the DB?

Comment: I' m using https://neo4j.com/developer/guide-neo4j-browser/ that browser for execute cypher

I get some nodes and relations and then 
I want to get cypher query which can add this nodes to database with this relation

Comment: I think you need to better explain your intent. My guess right now is that you want to create some kind of meta graph using nodes and relationships from your graph...are you trying to show what node labels there are, what relationships there are, and show how they relate?

Comment: Thanks 
I find answer